# Unable to connect to google play services, always get connection failed error

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

I have following simple code to get the last location:

**build.gardle** file for dependencies:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.naresh2575.location"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.0'
}
```

In manifest file, I am using following permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Here is my activity file:

```
public class MainActivity
        extends AppCompatActivity
        implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
{

    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    TextView tvLatLong;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tvLatLong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLatLong);
        buildGoogleApiClient();
    }

    protected void onStart() {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        super.onStart();
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient()
    {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint)
    {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            return;
        }
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null)
        {
            tvLatLong.setText("Latitude: " + String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()) + " Longitude: " + String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
        }
        else
        {
            tvLatLong.setText("mLastLocation is null");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Connection suspended...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to connect...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

The above code is very simple but when I run my application, I always get the message "Failed to connect..." written in the **onConnectionFailed**. It means I am not able to connect to the google play services. Where I need to look for it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to create a project in google developer console with SHA-1 key? After creating project you can handle  authentication key from console and you can solve this problem by using this authentication key.